# Python Loop Questions

Tags: python, function, loops, input, range

Write a Python program to construct the following pattern, using a nested for loop.

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```

Pictorial Presentation:

Python Exercise: Construct a specified pattern, using a nested for loop

Comment: First try to correct the formatting of your question. If you can't be bothered to ask a readable question, I won't bother to answer either.

Comment: _Write a Python program_ Have you actually attempted this part?  I don't see any code...

Answer (score -1):

```
n=6;
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i):
        print ('* ', end="")
    print('')

for i in range(n,0,-1):
    for j in range(i):
        print('* ', end="")
    print('')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?